# How to access an inetd service?

Tags: c, inetd

So I created a simple inetd error logging service according to this example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *fn = argv[1];
  FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "a+");

  if (fp == NULL) 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  char str[4096];
  /* inetd passes its information to us in stdin. */
  while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
    fputs(str, fp);
    fflush(fp);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I appended this line to `/etc/services/`

```
errorLogger 9999/udp
```

and this line to `/etc/inetd.conf`

```
errorLogger dgram udp wait root /usr/local/bin/errlogd errlogd /tmp/logfile.txt
```

How can I access this now?
I configured the service on my Raspberry Pi in my local network. Do I need to write a client program that accesses the UDP port 9999 or can I do it via SSH?

I already tried

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi -p 9999
```

but it says `ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 9999: Connection refused`

I also reload the systemd service with

```
sudo service inetd reload
```

and it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention a logging service, you can write to it with the `logger` command:

```bsh
logger --udp --port 9999 --server 127.0.0.1 'test msg'
```

Another versatile utility is `socat`:

```
echo 'test msg' | socat -u - udp-sendto:127.0.0.1:9999
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a listening service on the UDP port 9999. In order to write to this you need to use a tool that can create UDP packets, and `ssh` is not one of these.

The `netcat` tool can generate UDP packets, for example the version I have is used like this,

```
echo hello | nc -u -q1 remoteHost 9999    # Some versions of nc still also need "-w1"
```

Comment: Oh right. SSH is TCP based like Telnet. Would it work with SSH if I change the protocol?

Comment: No it wouldn't. An `ssh` client expects a chatty server. Your server express a chatty client

Comment: That is weird. We have the task in Uni to set up an inetd service that logs data into a file and are given the instructions to connect to it via Telnet.

Comment: With TCP/IP, `telnet` could work, but `ssh` will not